# How to make Spring load a JDBC Driver BEFORE initializing Hibernate's SessionFactory?

Tags: hibernate, spring, loading, jdbc

I'm developing a Spring(2.5.6)+Hibernate(3.2.6) web application to connect to a custom database. For that I have custom JDBC Driver and Hibernate Dialect. I know for sure that these custom classes work (hard coded stuff on my unit tests).

The problem, I guess, is with the order on which things get loaded by Spring. 
Basically:

1. Custom Database initializes
2. Spring load beans from web.xml
3. Spring loads ServletBeans(applicationContext.xml)
4. Hibernate kicks in: shows version and all the properties correctly loaded.
5. Hibernate's HbmBinder runs (maps all my classes)
6. LocalSessionFactoryBean - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
7. DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: MyCustomJDBCDriver at CustomDBURL
8. **I get a SQLException: No suitable driver found for CustomDBURL**
9. Hibernate loads the Custom Dialect
10. **My CustomJDBCDriver finally gets registered with DriverManager (log messages)**
11. SettingsFactory runs
12. SchemaExport runs (hbm2ddl)
13. **I get a SQLException: No suitable driver found for CustomDBURL (again?!)**
14. Application get successfully deployed but there are no tables on my custom Database.

Things that I tried so far:

- Different techniques for passing hibernate properties: embedded in the 'sessionFactory' bean, loaded from a hibernate.properties file. Nothing worked but I didn't try with hibernate.cfg.xml file neither with a dataSource bean yet.
- MyCustomJDBCDriver has a static initializer block that registers it self with the DriverManager.
- Tried different combinations of lazy initializing (lazy-init="true") of the Spring beans but nothing worked.

My custom JDBC driver should be the first thing to be loaded - not sure if by Spring but...!

Can anyone give me a solution for this or maybe a hint for what else I could try? I can provide more details (huge stack traces for instance) if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on which environnement are you seeing this problem ? spring context aware unit test ? jboss deployement ? (Could that be a classloader problem : Are you for example using a jboss distribution that includes hibernate in servers/ctxt/lib and that the driver lib is in your war ?)

Comment: Hi Thierry, I am trying to deploy the application in a local Jetty server for testing. Actually, is a little bit more complicated than that: Jetty is running inside a container of a Processing Unit(PU). So, the PU starts than it creates and starts the Jetty container. Jetty does the rest(WebAppContext is later registered with the PU).  How can I track on which classloader my CustomJDBCDriver is beind loaded and the one that Spring is?
Thanks!

Comment: Finally one of my colleagues at work found the solution for me. As @Thierry mentioned, it was a classloader problem. I was deploying my app with Spring libraries but the Processing Unit had those already loaded (lib folder of Jetty). So they were in conflict. The solution I found was to put my CustomJDBCDriver.jar in the same folder where the Spring jars are(jetty lib folder or from the apps /WEB-INF/lib), and make sure there is only one. That was it! Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

If Hibernate is responsible for getting database connections, then the hibernate properties [needs to include](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc) the `hibernate.connection.driver_class` property.

In your case:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = CustomJDBCDriver
```

Comment: Hi skaffman,
I have included the driver_class exactly the way you said - and I can see it gets loaded on Hibernate log - and the driver gets loaded and registered with the DriverManager. So that's not the answer to my question yet.
Thanks anyway.